# c# split string by random length

Tags: c#

lets say i have an string like the below:

```
AAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCC
```

Currently my code can only split the above string equally by the len that I use as parameter using the function below:

```
 private static IEnumerable<string> SplitByLength(string str, int maxLength)
    {
        for (var index = 0; index < str.Length; index += maxLength)
            yield return str.Substring(index, Math.Min(maxLength, str.Length - index));
    }
```

but this isnt what i want, I want the string to be splitted to random len, lets say between 2 to 10 char. example:

```
AAA
ABBBBB
BB
BBBCCC
C
```

the split len should be random. any hints how can I make it?

Comment: Take the length of the string as the upper bound, 2 as the lower bound and call Random.Next(). Use the resulting number to split the string.

Comment: @xxbbcc can I ask your help to write me a function to do it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=net-6.0#system-random-next(system-int32-system-int32)

Comment: @EmilyWong Read the documentation of the Random class and experiment with it to see how it works. If someone writes this for you, you'll never learn how to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works.

```
private static List<string> SplitString(string input)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();

        var tempString = input;
        var testString = "";
        while (true)
        {
            var maxInt = tempString.Length <= 35 ? tempString.Length : 35;

            var minInt = tempString.Length <= 10 ? tempString.Length : 10;

            var random1 = Random.Next(minInt, maxInt);

            result.Add(tempString.Substring(0, random1));
            testString += tempString.Substring(0, random1);
            tempString = tempString.Remove(0, random1);
            
            if (tempString.Length == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

      
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> SplitByLength(string str, int maxLength)
{
    var random = new Random();
    var count = Math.Min(random.Next(1, maxLength + 1), str.Length);

    int index = 0;
    while (index < str.Length)
    {                
        yield return str.Substring(index, count);

        index += count;
        count = Math.Min(random.Next(1, maxLength + 1), str.Length - index);
    }
}
```